# Visual studio keyboard shortcut for css color highlight

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

What is the keyboard shortcut to display the color tip?

I used to hover the color to get color tip but since I have applied `editor.hover.enabled: false` its doesn't display anymore. I want to keep my hover disabled but need a keyboard shortcut to display the color tip.

[image: CSS color highlight]

Comment: as far as im aware that is a known issue and discussion and there still is no shortcut for this. Only solution would be to use an extension

Comment: the default hover delay time was very short, if you increase `editor.hover.delay` you are not bothered by annoying tool tips when you move the mouse but only when you actually want a tool tip or color edit

Answer (score 0):

`editor.action.showHover` command will do what you want even with `editor.hover.enabled: false`.  When your cursor is on the color.

It is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> by default.

Comment: do i have to enable editor.action.showHover:true in settings?

Comment: No, (there is no `showHover` setting) just use its keybinding or bind it to some other keybinding if you wish.